# i want a login system in php codeigniter mvc or hmvc in which user can login through his account or through facebook account or gmail account

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

[image]

Could someone please help me. I want to make a login like this in `codeigniter`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "IonAuth" is the best library for login and user management. But you need to integrate facebook and other social media login manually which is easy with this library.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many authentication libraries available for codeigniter.
[Aauth](https://github.com/magefly/CodeIgniter-Aauth) is one of it .Please go through their documentation to know how to install.

**Basic properties of aauth**

```
    $this->load->library("Aauth"); // Loads aauth library
```

Creating a user

```
    $this->aauth->create_user($email, $pass, $username)
```

Login with username'

```
$this->aauth->login($identifier, $pass)
Identifier : email/username ( can change with ./config/aauth.php )
```

Checks whether logged or not

$this->aauth->is_loggedin()

To logout

```
$this->aauth->logout()
```

**Social Login**

- First create appropriate credentials
  ex for google , Goto google api console and create google+ api

Use [Hybridigniter](https://github.com/andacata/HybridIgniter) to social authentications easily .

1. Copy and paste hybridigniter files to your application folder
2. Update ./config/hybridauthlib.php with appropriate credentials

To get a social profile

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/index.php/hauth/login/Twitter">Log in with Twitter</a><br />
```

**Integrating Hybridigniter and Aauth**

After getting a profile You can create or login

Login

```
$this->aauth->login_fast($identifier)
```